# how to randomly assign a list of 20 names into 4 groups in matlab without repeating

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, random, grouping

I need to randomly select names from a list and randomly place them into a defined number of groups. For instance, I have 20 names in a list and I want my code to randomly pick a name and place them into one of the 4 groups till the end of the list. At the end of the code, I would like to output the names for each generated group or team.

This is what I have so far however it is not working.

```
data = readtable("NameList (2).xlsx");

%Check and make sure the script is accurately pulling names
Names = (data{:,1}); disp(Names)

%Arranging and Organizing Data
number_of_people = numel(data);
%Scramble array
s= number_of_people(randperm(length(number_of_people)))
number_of_groups = 4; 
divisions = sort(randperm(number_of_people-1, number_of_groups-1) + 1, 'ascend')
divisions = [0, divisions, number_of_people] 

%Cell array that will hold the groups
groups = cell(1, number_of_groups);

 for i= 1:number_of_groups
    indexes = divisions(i)+1;                                                         
  usersInThisGroups = length(indexes);
  fprintf('Assigning %d participant (indexes %d to %d) to group %d.\n', ...
    usersInThisGroups, divisions(i)+1,divisions(i+1), i);
  groups{i} = s(indexes);
 end
 
celldisp(groups); % Display groups in command window.
```

Comment: Is the total exactly divisible by the number of groups? (I.e., is it always 20 and 4 or could it be something else?) Do you need the groups to be the same size? (Or as near as possible to the same size)

Comment: @James it can be any combination of names and groups (ex 17 names for 4 groups). As near as possible to the same size for 17 and 4 for example, group1 can have 5 names; group2 has 4 names  group3 4 names...ect.

Comment: Generate a random permutation of the names and place 1-5 in group 1, 6-10 in group 2, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the number of elements in each group to be as near as possible, I suggest that you determine the size of 2D array first. Then assign all people into 2D array randomly. Mine implementation is as following:

```
data = readtable("NameList (2).xlsx");

%Check and make sure the script is accurately pulling names
Names = (data{:,1}); disp(Names)


number_of_people = numel(data);
number_of_groups = 4; 

%Initialize array
num_of_element_group = uint32(ceil(number_of_people/4))
groups = cell(number_of_groups, num_of_element_group);

%Initialize a random array
rand_num_arr = randperm(number_of_people)

%Using random array to assign people to group randomly
for i=0:number_of_people-1 %Iteration of the people list
    groups(mod(i,number_of_groups)+1, floor(i/number_of_groups)+1) = ... 
    Names(rand_num_arr(i+1)) %Assign the cell with randomly selected name    
end

celldisp(groups); % Display groups in command window.
```

Comment: This works thanks! - just need to figure out how to fill names by column.